# C# How to set a default value for automatic properties?

Tags: c#, interface, default-value

I have some interface and class implementing that interface:

```
public interface IWhatever {
   bool Value { get; set;}
}

public class Whatever : IWhatever {
   public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

*Now, does `C#` allow the `Value` to have some default value **without using some backing field?***

Comment: Do you mean can you specify the default e.g. in this example let Value default to True?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update**

As of C# 6 (VS2015) this syntax is perfectly valid

```
public bool Value { get; set; } = true;
```

as is setting a value for a readonly property

```
public bool Value { get; } = true;
```

**The old, pre C# 6 answer**

*Spoiler alert for those of an excitable nature*: **The following code will not work**

Are you asking, "Can I do this?"

```
public bool Value { get; set; } = true;
```

No, you can't. You need to set the default value in the constructor of the class

Comment: When I first saw that code sample I thought "No way! You can do that?!"

Comment: Actually think this answer should be updated because as of C#6, this is valid!! (hurrah!)

Comment: @Moo-Juice Thanks oh milky one! I updated the answer :)

Comment: @BinaryWorrier, I think you deserve a badge for getting the syntax right half a decade in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

If there's nothing behind it, it defaults to false, according to the documentation.

However, if you want it to be instantiated with an initial value *other than* `false`, you can do that this way:

```
public interface IWhatever 
{
   bool Value { get; set;}
}

public class Whatever : IWhatever 
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }

    public Whatever()
    { 
        Value = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant, like, for example to set it to `true`.

Comment: @Yippie No, C# doesn't allow you to do that. If you want it to have an initial value without a backing field, you need to set it in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The default value right now is `false`. To make it `true`, set it in the constructor.

```
public class Whatever : IWhatever 
{
   public bool Value { get; set; }
   public Whatever()
   {
       this.Value = true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `Value` would be `false` but it can be initialized in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set `Value` to any other default value than the default value of the datatype itself at the property. You need to assign the default value in the constructor of `Whatever`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value in the constructor.

```
//constructor
public Whatever()
{
   Value = true;
}

public bool Value { get; set; }
```

By the way - with automatic properties, you still have a backing field, it just gets generated for your by the compiler ([syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)).